# Why are $PAP^{-1}$ and $P^{-1}AP$ equal when changing base?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

I have a doubt about performing changes of basis in linear algebra. I know that for each pair of bases, say $B$ and $C$, I can find a certain "translation" matrix $P$ that sends my vectors in base $B$ to the corresponding vectors in base $C$. Furthermore, the inverse $P^{-1}$ performs the same transformation, just the opposite way: sending the vectors in base $C$ to their correspondents in base $B$.

Now, let $A$ be a certain matrix that describes a transformation over the space in relation to vectors expressed in the base $B$. My teacher gave me the definition of the matrix $A'$, describing the same transformation of vectors in base $C$, as:

$$
A' = P^{-1}AP
$$

which makes sense, as I am taking a vector in base $C$, throwing it into base $B$ by using $P$, performing my transformation $A$ and then throwing it back into base $C$ using $P^{-1}$. Problem is, I have also found the formula:

$$
A' = PAP^{-1}
$$

which seems to do the exact same thing, although I don't really understand how: it would seem that I'd be taking my vector in base $C$ and then using the transformation from base $B$ to base $C$ on it, which I can't in anyway get to make sense. Hope someone can help clarify this for me.

Comment: Where you write $A^{-1}$ in the transformed spaces, you presumably want to write $A'$. How do you come about the second formula from the first?

Comment: It's probably helpful to see (by making sketches) what happens geometrically with specific $2\times 2$ real matrices. Perhaps let $P$ be a shear along the $x$-axis and $A$ a scaling by different amounts along the coordinate axes. Then run through your argument to see where it goes awry.

Comment: Sorry! I got it it wrong, I meant to write A'. Fixing it now...

Comment: It would be helpful to include the sources of these formulae, and particularly the definitions of $A,A',P$ of the second formula.